# How to make images fill my carousel slides

Tags: html, reactjs, thumbnails, tailwind-css, web-frontend

I am trying to fit my images into the slides.

Below is my example code and screenshots:

```
<div className="relative h-24 w-20 sm:h-44 sm:w-100 md:h-44 md:w-60 flex-shrink-0">
  <Carousel showThumbs={false}>
    {imgSrc?.map((url, index) => (
      <div className="h-24 w-20 sm:h-44 sm:w-100 md:h-44 md:w-60 flex-shrink-0" >
        <img class="object-fill rounded-md" src={`${url}`} />
      </div>
    ))}
  </Carousel>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

What I have done is:

1. Set the first  block into fix size. This is the size I want every image will be constrained into.
2. Inside the Carousel: Since the `<div>` and `<img>` tags are the protocol in this library. So I'm just following it.
3. To make sure everything will be constrained into fixed length. I set same CSS rule to every tag.

The result is that not all images display the same size. Some have some empty space which I don't want to see.

May I know how to fix it? Isn't this the way of this CSS is intended to be used?

---

[updated with Ed Lucas's code]

In MD setting, all the images in thumbnail are perfectly fitted into the box.

However, when screen shrinks, some images suddenly **shrink smaller than** the thumbnail while some could still align with the box size. Do you know any ideas?

```
<div className="relative h-30 w-40 sm:h-44 sm:w-100 md:h-44 md:w-60 flex-shrink-0">
  <Carousel showThumbs={false}>
    {imgSrc?.map((url, index) => (
      <div className="h-30 w-40 sm:h-44 sm:w-100 md:h-44 md:w-60 flex-shrink-0" >
        <img class="object-cover h-full w-full rounded-md" src={`${url}`} />
      </div>
    ))}
  </Carousel>
</div>
```

Here is example in small screen size

normal:

[image]

abnormal pictures

[image]

Comment: Please could you put up a snippet which shows us the resultant HTML/CSS from whatever pre-processor(s) you are using.

Comment: what do you mean by resultant html/css? you meant the whole html and css file?

Comment: Hi, no, just enough of the relevant HTML and CSS which demonstrates the problem, not the contents of the files which are in some other language. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Haworth, Actually the html and css above is the actual code and directly linked to the screenshot I posted. May I know which part you confuse?

Comment: The code you are showing isn't HTML or CSS. What pre processor are you using?

Comment: Oh, its within react js code. its a jsx that will then turns into html and css. Actually it is quite similar to html

Comment: Are you using tailwind css? If so, please remove the CSS tag and use tailwind-css one.

Comment: Chnaged, thanks. May I know that you see this post becasue of this css tag ?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property in CSS.
the same property in tailwind is found [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/object-fit)

Comment: still not working. the problems are still existing... Not all images display the same size. Some have some empty space.

Comment: maybe if I see the code I can try.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the width and height on your container `<div>`, you can use `object-fill` with 100% width and height. For example, if you don't mind your image being stretched:

```
<img class="object-fill h-full w-full rounded-md" src={`${url}`} />
```

If you don't want a stretched image, you can try `object-cover`:

```
<img class="object-cover h-full w-full rounded-md" src={`${url}`} />
```

Comment: It works Ed Lucas! , I would like to ask one more question. I don't quite understand why both can constrain image in the same-size container, but aspect ration is not preserved in fill but it does in cover.

Comment: With cover, a portion of the image is cropped in one of the dimensions instead of being stretched to fit.

Comment: I see, so , in this example, either the width or height of image was filled into the container  with original aspect ratio first. and then, we just simply crop out the the other side that didnt fit into the container?

Comment: Yes. Generally, the image is centered so that it is cropped on two sides.

Comment: Hi Lucas, one more question, I have updated my code with your code, with the result above. But, why would some images shrink smaller than the container, and how to avoid it? @Ed Lucas